# Dimensions of a substituted symbol

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Best way to get the Dimension of a till now unknown symbol.

For example:

```
foo = Dimensions[undefined][[1,1]];
foo /.undefined -> {{1,2},{3,4}}
```

Theses lines of code do not work. Does anyone know, how to write this correctly?
I have to import the the values by substitutions. 'foo' as a function and 'a' as a parameter is unfortunately no alternative for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea in your self-answer and I voted for it.  However you should be aware that `MatrixQ` is not as general as you might want.  For example a three dimensional tensor will fail it:

```
tensor = RandomInteger[9, {3, 2, 4}];

MatrixQ[tensor]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

`Dimensions` can be used on an expression that is not even a `List`:

```
f[f[1, 2], f[3, 3]] // Dimensions
```

> ```
> {2, 2}
> ```

Further your use of `Part` is not correct.  Note the warning message:

```
dim[undefined][[1, 1]]
```

> During evaluation of In[106]:= Part::partd: Part specification dim[undefined][[1,1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
>
> ```
>  dim[undefined][[1, 1]]
> ```

There is no part (1, 1) in the output of `Dimensions`.  If you instead use `[[1]]` you will simply extract `undefined` from `dim[undefined]`.  Instead you should include the part extraction in the definition of `dim`, or if you have *Mathematica* 10+ you can use `Indexed`.

I propose:

```
dims[x : _[__], part__: All] := Dimensions[x][[part]]
```

Now:

```
dims[undefined] /. undefined -> tensor
```

> ```
> {3, 2, 4}
> ```

```
dims[undefined, 1] /. undefined -> tensor
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

```
 dims[undefined, 2] /. undefined -> f[f[1, 2], f[3, 3]]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

---

Visit the dedicated *Mathematica* Stack Exchange site:

[image: Mathematica.StackExchange]

Answer (score 1):

I found a possibility:

Need to wrap 'Dimensions'

```
dim[x_?MatrixQ] := Dimensions[x];
...
foo = dim[undefined][[1,1]];
foo /.undefined -> {{1,2},{3,4}}
```

This works!